# Cannot find .idea/misc.xml when building in Android Studio

Tags: android, build, android-studio

I'm attempting to build a signed apk of a project in Android Studio. I am getting the following error.

```
Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) /home/stegosaurus/AndroidStudio/.idea/misc.xml (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/stegosaurus/AndroidStudio/.idea/misc.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:340)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:99)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

as I have never been using Android Studio I am not experienced with this tool. But Android Studio is based on IntelliJ idea in which - some time ago - I ran into the same Exception while trying to run an application.

I don't know your project source/structure but try to reimport your project with 'File -> Import Project'. Do NOT use the project sources Android Studio is generating but overwrite these when you are asked for it during the import process! (Android Studio project files are *.iml files) For me it solved the issue.

If this is not the issue with your build please provide some more detailed information.

Greetings